# ASP.Net Membership with multiple user accounts for different applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm creating an ASP.NET website and intend to have multiple "Applications", each with its own set of users. Effectively I need a way to have different groups that people can register with, so "UserA" can be created in "ApplicationA" and "UserA" can also be created in "ApplicationB". I do *not* want UserA to be created in all Applications, the user has to feel as though they're creating a separate user account for each application.

I *think* I can do this with ASP.NET's Membership provider and the Applications table, but I'm having a hard time finding good tutorials on how to do this (searching on "Applications" just leads me to how to create ASP.NET Applications, not how the Applications table relates to the ASP.NET Membership). Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for `Single Sign On` capability (across different ASP.Net applications). See if [this Codeplex project](http://wcfsso.codeplex.com/) helps you (or even solves everything for you). The key term to search for (if it doesn't) is "Single Sign On (SSO)"

Comment: Actually just the opposite. I don't want any user to be able to use the same account for different applications, but I do want them to be able to recreate the same account if they so desire.

Imagine if my website was a backend for two different book store applications, like say Barnes & Noble and Amazon. To the end user, they don't know that the backend is shared, and so when they go to Amazon, they would expect to create a new account even if they have an account at Barnes & Noble. And they would even expect to be able to create the same account name.

Comment: Then see the link that @urlreader provided - particularly the section on setting `applicationName`. Can't seem to add the Url to Scott Guthrie's blog linked in the tutorial (since it contains characters not being parsed by SO properly - "_"), but it's in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use ASP.Net Membership for your applications that you have stated.

Please use new [ASP.Net Universal Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx). (Membership which generates aspnet_xxx tables is an old one.)

Also make sure to set the following in web.config -

1. set `applicationName` (in membership, roleManager) for each appliation.
2. set `machineKey`

Answer (score 0):

here is the schema:
http://superpatrick.files.wordpress.com/2007/11/aspnet_membership_schema_updated.png

here is some info about the membership
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb

Comment: I am familiar with the schema (my Applications table looks different, no lowercase name field), and I've seen that tutorial before. Neither helped with what I'm hoping to do, which is all a user to create multiple accounts with the same username but for different applications...